# Удаление сообщений

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, написал скрипт удаления сообщений, но почему то действе не происходит. Выводиться только окно комформа и все ... В чем может быть проблема ? Заранее спасибо!

```
        $('.dt').click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = 'tid='+ ID;
    if(confirm("Yes or No ?"))
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dx.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){ $("#" + ID + ".tx").animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);},   
  success: function(html){
     $("#" + ID + ".tx").fadeOut(300,function(){$("#" + ID + ".tx").remove();});
     }
     });
    }
    return false;
    });
```

Само сообщение которое удаляется имеет вид

```
<div id="12" class="tx" />blabl</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id-шки элементов не должны начинаться с числа.
Измените id блока, поставив перед числом какую нить букву, a12 к примеру.

Comment: Вы думаете проблема только в этом или есть еще что нибудь что навредило выполнению скрипта ?

Comment: Кстати лишний слеш в div-е это опечатка? В реальном коде надеюсь его нет?

Comment: Это опечатка извините, в реально такого точно нету. Огромное спасибо за то что помогли